# converting a list of string to integers starting at 0 to 1 to

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, google-sheets

I was just wondering how I would convert these lists of unknowing strings to a list of integers, starting at 0, to 1, to 2, and so forth, and this is in collaboration of the Google Sheets API.
Here are the circumstances:
Credits to the Sheets API Overview Page from Google, I have this

```
foreach (SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries)
  {
    // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
  }
```

Now instead of wanting it to just Debug the strings of a retrieved list off of Google Spreadsheets, I want to convert it into Values/Integers, so it could work with this chunk:

```
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet2 = (SpreadsheetEntry)feed.Entries[The solution to the code above];
```

Thanks for reading guys! :)

Comment: are you wanting to have a `List<T> of type int..?` if so this is quite simple have you done a google search on List<int>` also google `initialize List<int> examples`

Comment: uh could you by any chance elaborate on this? How will it convert or assign my list of strings an integer starting at 0?

Comment: this is quite simple I will post an example of what you can do with List<T> as well as with dynamic string[] arrray or List<object> etc to give you an Idea.. this is not that difficult you need to understand what Generics are and how powerful they can be if used properly..

Comment: look at my example below and try to understand the how and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example lets imagine that you have want to populate a `List<string> , List<int> or List<object>` with some values and you want avoid populating the List using a for loop or a foreach loop you can do the following 
`1st` example I will populate a List from a dynamic empty string array {}`

```
   string[] bargeArr = { };
   var bargeList = new List<string>
   {
       "ticketid",
       "refno",
       "movetype",
       "measurementtype"
   };
   bargeArr = bargeList.ToArray();//use the debugger to see that the list has strings
```

`2nd` example I will create a `List<object>` with string, int, and Collection

```
   bargeArr = bargeList.ToArray();
   var bargeList2 = new List<object>
   {
       "SirSirX",
       1,
       new List<string>{"Conal", "MoneyBags"},
       "measurementtype"
   };
   var bargeArr2 = bargeList2.ToArray();//notice the List<object> holds different data types
```

now you can mess around and do the same thing even if you did the following store the values in a List from a for loop

```
List<int> someIntList = new List<int>();
for (var intCount = 0; intCount < 10; intCount++)
{
    someIntList.Add(intCount);
}
```

your List will be populated with values from `0 to 9`

Comment: Thank you! this was greatly helpful!